# executing (triggering submit) two form from Java scripts

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have two forms in the same page and each has a submit button. I have Java script that updates the second form based on the first form. executing (pressing submit) on the form will open a new tab with some data.

From my java script I am doing this :

document.form1.submit();
document.form2.submit();

But this produces only one new tab, instead of opening both tabs. If I put the form2 statement before form1, then only the page associated with form2 open in new tab and the page linked to form1 does not.
why would this happen and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had once used this ,hope it helps

```
<script language="javascript">
function() submitForms{
document.getElementById("firstform").submit();
document.getElementById("secondform").submit();
}
</script>

<form id="firstform" target="iframe1">
</form><iframe name="iframe1" style="display:none"></iframe>
<form id="secondform" target="iframe2">
</form><iframe name="iframe1" style="display:none"></iframe>
<button onclick="submitForms()"><img src="images/order-button.png" "/></button>
```

Comment: No,that still is triggering the first form only.

Answer (score 0):

The browsers popup blockers usually only allow one popup per click. Forms opening a new tab will also count as popups.

You have three possible ways to go (that I can find):

1. Open one new tab and load the second one in the same window.
2. Ask your users to allow the second popup
3. Force the user to click on two different buttons

Comment: opening in the same window did not work either. the second window just won't open.